# Vue 3 - Image relative path syntax (inside method)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, methods

I'm currently build a little component with an image fallback, it should be implemented like this:

```
export default {
  name: "ChannelHeader",
  props: ['channel'],
  methods : {
    channelLogo(channel) {
      if(channel?.thumbnails?.high) return channel.thumbnails.high
      if(channel?.thumbnails?.medium) return channel.thumbnails.medium
      if(channel?.thumbnails?.default) return channel.thumbnails.default
      return "~@/assets/material_header_medium.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

when all fails the channelLogo should been loaded from assets folder this works all fine beside that the URL is not redered.

the html for the logo is:

```
 <img uk-cover :src="channelLogo()" :alt="channel?.title+' Logo'">
```

And rendered:

```
<img uk-cover="" src="~@/assets/material_header_medium.jpg" alt="undefined Logo" data-v-5d87ed20="" class="uk-cover" style="height: 70px; width: 70px;">
```

In the same component i use this image as div background:

```
.channel-header{
  background-image: url("~@/assets/material_header_medium.jpg");
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

So how is the Syntax to give back those relative paths from a method?

Comment: You need tu use `require()` - `return require("~@/assets/material_header_medium.jpg")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned by Vucko it was needed to wrap the path into a required. but it will not work when using:

```
return require("~@/assets/material_header_medium.jpg")
```

i had to use:

```
return require("@/assets/material_header_medium.jpg")
```

As an alternative i have first importet the media and used it later:

```
import fallbackImage from '@/assets/material_header_medium.jpg'

...

return fallbackImage
```